# First C++ Program Getting Errors

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Ok so for an assignment we have to make our first program. Mine is to make a program that calculates the ticket revenue for each seating section at a theater. The problem is that I keep getting this undeclared identifier or identifier undefined error along with like 23 other errors. The program I am using is Visual Studio 2010 Premium.

Here is my code.

```
// Chp4HWprgm.cpp 
// Created by Bryce Easley on 2/6/2012
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
//declare variables

int orchestraNum = 0;
int mainNum = 0;
int balconyNum =0;
const orchestraPrice = 25;
const mainPrice = 30;
const balconyPrice = 15;

//enter input of sales
cout << "Number of Orchestra tickets sold?";
cin >> orchestraNum;
cout << "Number of Main Floor tickets sold?";
cin >> mainNum;
cout << "Number of Balcony tickets sold?";
cin >> balconyNum;

//calculate revenue for each and total revenue
orchestraTotal = orchestraNum * orchestraPrice;
mainTotal = mainNum * mainPrice;
balconyTotal = balconyNum * balconyPrice;
overallTotal = mainTotal + balconyTotal + orchestraTotal;

//display figures
cout <<"Orchestra Revenue: $" << orchestraTotal << endl;
cout <<"Main Floor Revenue: $" << mainTotal << endl;
cout <<"Balcony Revenue: $" << balconyTotal << endl;
cout <<"Overall Revenue: $" << overallTotal << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;}
//end of main function
```

Here are my errors:

> Error 6   error C2065: 'balconyTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 28  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 9   error C2065: 'balconyTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 29  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 13  error C2065: 'balconyTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 34  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 5   error C2065: 'mainTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 27  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 8   error C2065: 'mainTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 29  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 12  error C2065: 'mainTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 33  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 4   error C2065: 'orchestraTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 26  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 10  error C2065: 'orchestraTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 29  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 11  error C2065: 'orchestraTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 32  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 7   error C2065: 'overallTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 29  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 14  error C2065: 'overallTotal' : undeclared
>   identifier    c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 35  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support
>   default-int   c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 13  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support
>   default-int   c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 14  1   Chapter4HW
>   Error 3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support
>   default-int   c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 15  1   Chapter4HW
>     15  IntelliSense: explicit type is missing ('int'
>   assumed)  c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 13  7   Chapter4HW
>     16  IntelliSense: explicit type is missing ('int'
>   assumed)  c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 14  7   Chapter4HW
>     17  IntelliSense: explicit type is missing ('int'
>   assumed)  c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 15  7   Chapter4HW
>     20  IntelliSense: identifier "balconyTotal" is
>   undefined c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 28  1   Chapter4HW
>     19  IntelliSense: identifier "mainTotal" is
>   undefined c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 27  1   Chapter4HW
>     18  IntelliSense: identifier "orchestraTotal" is
>   undefined c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 26  1   Chapter4HW
>     21  IntelliSense: identifier "overallTotal" is
>   undefined c:\users\bryce\desktop\cpp6\chap04\chapter4hw\chapter4hw\chp4hw.cpp 29  1   Chapter4HW

Gracias to everyone that answered. I seriously stared at this forever and I couldnt figure it out. It's like learning a whole new language and it's a bit confusing!

Comment: you didn't declare you total variables...

Comment: You're getting it because you didn't declare the variables...

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with your error messages, but `system("pause");` always gives me -- er, pause. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1107705/10077

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your constants and total variables with types:

```
const int orchestraPrice = 25; 
const int mainPrice = 30; 
const int balconyPrice = 15;

...

//calculate revenue for each and total revenue 
int orchestraTotal = orchestraNum * orchestraPrice; 
int mainTotal = mainNum * mainPrice; 
int balconyTotal = balconyNum * balconyPrice; 
int overallTotal = mainTotal + balconyTotal + orchestraTotal;
```

Comment: The constants need types too.

Comment: Doesn't VC++ add unsigned int if it sees a variable declaration like "auto i" or "const i". It's only printing out errors for the "Total" variables.

Comment: it does, but thats not to say you should let it!

Answer (score 2):

Understanding compiler errors is something you'll soon learn, as you practise!

`const` isn't a type, it's a modifier. `orchestraPrice` should be declared:

```
const int orchestraPrice = 25;
```

You have three similar lines with the same problem.

And you haven't declared `orchestraTotal` before you use it. Try this instead:

```
const int orchestraTotal = orchestraNum * orchestraPrice;
```

Again, you have three similar lines with the same problem.

I recommend reading a book or two on C++. See [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) .

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the book. Right now we are reading in my intro class An Introduction to Programming with c++ by D.Zak

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables before you use or while you initialize them.

```
int orchestraTotal = orchestraNum * orchestraPrice;
int mainTotal = mainNum * mainPrice;
int balconyTotal = balconyNum * balconyPrice;
int overallTotal = mainTotal + balconyTotal + orchestraTotal;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not declared the 4 variables:

```
mainTotal, bacolnyTotal, orchestraTotal, overallTotal
```

Comment: The other common cause of this error is spelling and capitalization mismatches, which your answer has in spades.

Answer (score 0):

```
orchestraTotal = orchestraNum * orchestraPrice;
mainTotal = mainNum * mainPrice;
balconyTotal = balconyNum * balconyPrice;
overallTotal = mainTotal + balconyTotal + orchestraTotal;
```

Turn these into definitions and you should be fine. You don't declare or define any of these variables before using them, that's why the compiler is printing errors.